# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```py
fashion_model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics = ['accuracy']
)
```

When I execute this line of code I am facing the error

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'

and my tensorflow version is 2.0

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy

I also faced a similar issue then i called tensorflow with each Keras object and it resolved it

Answer (score 14):

substitute `tf.math.log` for `tf.log` in `tf 2.0`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact line where `tf.log` is, replace it with `tf.math.log`.
if not, you can use [this guide to Automatically upgrade code to TensorFlow 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/upgrade.ipynb)

Answer (score -1):

It is due to TensorFlow update.
Just do this:

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Then run your code